# Unable to use ProtobufUtil converting json to Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am trying to convert json to protobuf and trying to use [Protubuf utility][1] mentioned here. When I run this under main method, then it works perfectly fine. However, if I am using this in a application, then I see below exception:

````
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom([Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;
    at com.google.protobuf.AnyProto.<clinit>(AnyProto.java:39)
    at com.google.protobuf.Any.getDescriptor(Any.java:32)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.buildWellKnownTypeParsers(JsonFormat.java:1361)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.<clinit>(JsonFormat.java:1355)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:471)
    at com.opentable.extension.ProtobufUtil.fromJson(ProtobufUtil.java:13)```

  [1]: https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-json-protobuf#:~:text=We%20can%20convert%20JSON%20to,parse%20JSON%20to%20protobuf%20message.
````